# How to determine the minimal required .NET framework version to run my app

Tags: c#, .net

I have written c# console app. .NET Framework is by default set to version 4.5.
I want to know if there is a way, to test app with older versions of .NET framework or test, which version of framework app actually needs to run( without regarding targettype framework).

Comment: change the target framework in the project, see if it still compiles?

Comment: It depends on the code you have used. If you have used 4.5 libs then you will need v4.5.

Comment: @Lee well, even that isn't strictly true; a range of `Microsoft.Bcl` packages are available that add later BCL features into earlier frameworks; a lot of new compiler features that depend on those features will also then work against the earlier frameworks. Going back even further, there are things like LINQBridge which adds some 3.5 features into 2.0.

Comment: @JamesS "...and runs, and behaves the same" ;p

Comment: Is there a library with methods which are now in system.linq? because i'm only using system.linq, which is in 3.5 or later ...

Comment: @user3019122 LINQBridge: https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqBridge/

Comment: I don't think what you're asking will solve the underlying problem. Is your actual question _"On what .NET Framework can an application compiled against 4.5 run"_, or _"How to make my application run on all .NET Framework versions"_?

Comment: @MarcGravell ah - the ultimate completionist's test plan ;)

Comment: @CodeCaster well, I'm asking both questions.. I'm trying to make app run on all .NET frameworks, but if that isnt possible, I just need information on what versions can app be compiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was regarding the System.Linq library, which isn't supported in .NET framework 2.0.
As you can read in comments, I fixed this with using LINQBridge from nuGet. The other problem was, that framework 2.0 does not contain public method Dispose for HashAlgorithm. I solved this with using Clear method. All the other errors were fixed with reinstalling all nuget packages.

Comment: Don't you know that Microsoft no longer supports .NET 2.0 unless you have .NET 3.5 SP1 applied? If you know that, you should be able to stop right now, and focus on .NET 3.5+. Don't waste any more time on that. http://blogs.technet.com/b/lifecycle/archive/2010/04/30/net-framework-3-5-sp1-and-later-now-supported-as-part-of-microsoft-windows.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can add some entries to your app.config file to target a particular version of the framework, to override the version that it was built with. Obviously you still need to test that it works with these versions but this allows you to run on different versions of the framework:

```
<configuration>
  <!-- this is used if they only have net 4 installed-->
  <!--
  <runtime>
    <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
  -->
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: +1, perhaps you could add a remark about, or hint at, the `<requiredRuntime>` element as well?